# Port Scan Written in C with Proxy Support

Tags: c, tcp, proxy, port-scanning

port scan is probably done most efficiently in C code and actually got working code referenced from here - https://www.binarytides.com/tcp-syn-portscan-in-c-with-linux-sockets/

```
#include<stdio.h> //printf
#include<string.h> //memset
#include<stdlib.h> //for exit(0);
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<errno.h> //For errno - the error number
#include<pthread.h>
#include<netdb.h>   //hostend
#include<arpa/inet.h>
#include<netinet/tcp.h> //Provides declarations for tcp header
#include<netinet/ip.h>  //Provides declarations for ip header

void * receive_ack( void *ptr );
void process_packet(unsigned char* , int);
unsigned short csum(unsigned short * , int );
char * hostname_to_ip(char * );
int get_local_ip (char *);

struct pseudo_header    //needed for checksum calculation
{
    unsigned int source_address;
    unsigned int dest_address;
    unsigned char placeholder;
    unsigned char protocol;
    unsigned short tcp_length;
    
    struct tcphdr tcp;
};

struct in_addr dest_ip;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //Create a raw socket
    int s = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_RAW , IPPROTO_TCP);
    if(s < 0)
    {
        printf ("Error creating socket. Error number : %d . Error message : %s \n" , errno , strerror(errno));
        exit(0);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Socket created.\n");
    }
        
    //Datagram to represent the packet
    char datagram[4096];    
    
    //IP header
    struct iphdr *iph = (struct iphdr *) datagram;
    
    //TCP header
    struct tcphdr *tcph = (struct tcphdr *) (datagram + sizeof (struct ip));
    
    struct sockaddr_in  dest;
    struct pseudo_header psh;
    
    char *target = argv[1];
    
    if(argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Please specify a hostname \n");
        exit(1);
    }
    
    if( inet_addr( target ) != -1)
    {
        dest_ip.s_addr = inet_addr( target );
    }
    else
    {
        char *ip = hostname_to_ip(target);
        if(ip != NULL)
        {
            printf("%s resolved to %s \n" , target , ip);
            //Convert domain name to IP
            dest_ip.s_addr = inet_addr( hostname_to_ip(target) );
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Unable to resolve hostname : %s" , target);
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    
    int source_port = 43591;
    char source_ip[20];
    get_local_ip( source_ip );
    
    printf("Local source IP is %s \n" , source_ip);
    
    memset (datagram, 0, 4096); /* zero out the buffer */
    
    //Fill in the IP Header
    iph->ihl = 5;
    iph->version = 4;
    iph->tos = 0;
    iph->tot_len = sizeof (struct ip) + sizeof (struct tcphdr);
    iph->id = htons (54321);    //Id of this packet
    iph->frag_off = htons(16384);
    iph->ttl = 64;
    iph->protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
    iph->check = 0;     //Set to 0 before calculating checksum
    iph->saddr = inet_addr ( source_ip );   //Spoof the source ip address
    iph->daddr = dest_ip.s_addr;
    
    iph->check = csum ((unsigned short *) datagram, iph->tot_len >> 1);
    
    //TCP Header
    tcph->source = htons ( source_port );
    tcph->dest = htons (80);
    tcph->seq = htonl(1105024978);
    tcph->ack_seq = 0;
    tcph->doff = sizeof(struct tcphdr) / 4;     //Size of tcp header
    tcph->fin=0;
    tcph->syn=1;
    tcph->rst=0;
    tcph->psh=0;
    tcph->ack=0;
    tcph->urg=0;
    tcph->window = htons ( 14600 ); // maximum allowed window size
    tcph->check = 0; //if you set a checksum to zero, your kernel's IP stack should fill in the correct checksum during transmission
    tcph->urg_ptr = 0;
    
    //IP_HDRINCL to tell the kernel that headers are included in the packet
    int one = 1;
    const int *val = &one;
    
    if (setsockopt (s, IPPROTO_IP, IP_HDRINCL, val, sizeof (one)) < 0)
    {
        printf ("Error setting IP_HDRINCL. Error number : %d . Error message : %s \n" , errno , strerror(errno));
        exit(0);
    }
    
    printf("Starting sniffer thread...\n");
    char *message1 = "Thread 1";
    int  iret1;
    pthread_t sniffer_thread;

    if( pthread_create( &sniffer_thread , NULL ,  receive_ack , (void*) message1) < 0)
    {
        printf ("Could not create sniffer thread. Error number : %d . Error message : %s \n" , errno , strerror(errno));
        exit(0);
    }

    printf("Starting to send syn packets\n");
    
    int port;
    dest.sin_family = AF_INET;
    dest.sin_addr.s_addr = dest_ip.s_addr;
    for(port = 1 ; port < 100 ; port++)
    {
        tcph->dest = htons ( port );
        tcph->check = 0;    // if you set a checksum to zero, your kernel's IP stack should fill in the correct checksum during transmission
        
        psh.source_address = inet_addr( source_ip );
        psh.dest_address = dest.sin_addr.s_addr;
        psh.placeholder = 0;
        psh.protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
        psh.tcp_length = htons( sizeof(struct tcphdr) );
        
        memcpy(&psh.tcp , tcph , sizeof (struct tcphdr));
        
        tcph->check = csum( (unsigned short*) &psh , sizeof (struct pseudo_header));
        
        //Send the packet
        if ( sendto (s, datagram , sizeof(struct iphdr) + sizeof(struct tcphdr) , 0 , (struct sockaddr *) &dest, sizeof (dest)) < 0)
        {
            printf ("Error sending syn packet. Error number : %d . Error message : %s \n" , errno , strerror(errno));
            exit(0);
        }
    }
    
    pthread_join( sniffer_thread , NULL);
    printf("%d" , iret1);
    
    return 0;
}

/*
    Method to sniff incoming packets and look for Ack replies
*/
void * receive_ack( void *ptr )
{
    //Start the sniffer thing
    start_sniffer();
}

int start_sniffer()
{
    int sock_raw;
    
    int saddr_size , data_size;
    struct sockaddr saddr;
    
    unsigned char *buffer = (unsigned char *)malloc(65536); //Its Big!
    
    printf("Sniffer initialising...\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    
    //Create a raw socket that shall sniff
    sock_raw = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_RAW , IPPROTO_TCP);
    
    if(sock_raw < 0)
    {
        printf("Socket Error\n");
        fflush(stdout);
        return 1;
    }
    
    saddr_size = sizeof saddr;
    
    while(1)
    {
        //Receive a packet
        data_size = recvfrom(sock_raw , buffer , 65536 , 0 , &saddr , &saddr_size);
        
        if(data_size <0 )
        {
            printf("Recvfrom error , failed to get packets\n");
            fflush(stdout);
            return 1;
        }
        
        //Now process the packet
        process_packet(buffer , data_size);
    }
    
    close(sock_raw);
    printf("Sniffer finished.");
    fflush(stdout);
    return 0;
}

void process_packet(unsigned char* buffer, int size)
{
    //Get the IP Header part of this packet
    struct iphdr *iph = (struct iphdr*)buffer;
    struct sockaddr_in source,dest;
    unsigned short iphdrlen;
    
    if(iph->protocol == 6)
    {
        struct iphdr *iph = (struct iphdr *)buffer;
        iphdrlen = iph->ihl*4;
    
        struct tcphdr *tcph=(struct tcphdr*)(buffer + iphdrlen);
            
        memset(&source, 0, sizeof(source));
        source.sin_addr.s_addr = iph->saddr;
    
        memset(&dest, 0, sizeof(dest));
        dest.sin_addr.s_addr = iph->daddr;
        
        if(tcph->syn == 1 && tcph->ack == 1 && source.sin_addr.s_addr == dest_ip.s_addr )
        {
            printf("Port %d open \n" , ntohs(tcph->source));
            fflush(stdout);
        }
    }
}

/*
 Checksums - IP and TCP
 */
unsigned short csum(unsigned short *ptr,int nbytes) 
{
    register long sum;
    unsigned short oddbyte;
    register short answer;

    sum=0;
    while(nbytes>1) {
        sum+=*ptr++;
        nbytes-=2;
    }
    if(nbytes==1) {
        oddbyte=0;
        *((u_char*)&oddbyte)=*(u_char*)ptr;
        sum+=oddbyte;
    }

    sum = (sum>>16)+(sum & 0xffff);
    sum = sum + (sum>>16);
    answer=(short)~sum;
    
    return(answer);
}

/*
    Get ip from domain name
 */
char* hostname_to_ip(char * hostname)
{
    struct hostent *he;
    struct in_addr **addr_list;
    int i;
        
    if ( (he = gethostbyname( hostname ) ) == NULL) 
    {
        // get the host info
        herror("gethostbyname");
        return NULL;
    }

    addr_list = (struct in_addr **) he->h_addr_list;
    
    for(i = 0; addr_list[i] != NULL; i++) 
    {
        //Return the first one;
        return inet_ntoa(*addr_list[i]) ;
    }
    
    return NULL;
}

/*
 Get source IP of system , like 192.168.0.6 or 192.168.1.2
 */

int get_local_ip ( char * buffer)
{
    int sock = socket ( AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

    const char* kGoogleDnsIp = "8.8.8.8";
    int dns_port = 53;

    struct sockaddr_in serv;

    memset( &serv, 0, sizeof(serv) );
    serv.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(kGoogleDnsIp);
    serv.sin_port = htons( dns_port );

    int err = connect( sock , (const struct sockaddr*) &serv , sizeof(serv) );

    struct sockaddr_in name;
    socklen_t namelen = sizeof(name);
    err = getsockname(sock, (struct sockaddr*) &name, &namelen);

    const char *p = inet_ntop(AF_INET, &name.sin_addr, buffer, 100);

    close(sock);
}
```

And it works! But now I need to add **proxy support** to this C code.
Looking at the sockets documentation of C, it doesn't really have out of the box support for proxy connections. The idea I have in mind is that if proxy is required, I would need to start another proxy server socket to forward the packets...?

Can anyone give an idea of how I can go about doing this?

Comment: What type of proxy are you thinking of? In contrast to most normal use cases the proxy would have to support TCP SYN port scan or raw socket operations in general.

Comment: There is no established proxy protocol for what you are trying to do, i.e. sending raw IP packets. Neither HTTP proxy nor SOCKS proxy protocol support this. Sure you can make your own protocol but then you also need to implement the proxy and install it where needed.

Comment: I think I was thinking more of creating a C binary that can send raw IP packets via the proxy URL. Maybe the binary can be executed with an arg of e.g. --proxy socks5://127.0.0.1:1080